# A Voltage Divider with Load Regulation and Efficiency Question?

Tags: voltage-divider, load, regulations

For this question, the voltage divider splits the 12 V battery into +/- 6 V and it supplies up to 10 W total to the load, split between the two output voltage outputs in an arbitrary ration. Load regulation is intended to be greater than 1% from 0 W to 10 W. Now, in this case, the resistors, R, aren't the load resistors, the load resistors would be connected in parallel to the resistors, R

[image]

Now, what I need help on is approaching this problem. I think I managed to get the load resistors correct at 3.6 Ohms from 10 W / ((6 V)^2) but I'm not too sure

Comment: why would you set such resistors that low if their only purpose is to generate a pseudo split rail...

Comment: This design is not suitable to power _real_ sinks, it's only useful as reference voltage.

Comment: The divider will split the voltage only as long as the load current from V+ to GND is exactly the same as the current from GND to V-. If those two currents are not identical, then both voltages will deviate from Vb/2. Just FYI.

Comment: **JonRB** I was just going with what I think could perhaps work for load resistors connected in parallel to resistors, R. I doubt they're correct though. Honestly, I'm just confused as to how I should go about doing this problem **mkeith** That makes sense. In this case, however, the resistors, R, aren't the load resistors. The load resistors would be what's connected to the supply. I should've explained that better

Comment: Excuse me, but... what is the question?

Comment: The question is asking me to find the appropriate resistors that allows me to meet the load regulation with the given information

Answer (score 1):

The regulation of 1% should be taken into account when loads (not shown in your schema) are connected to this awful 'regulator'. Since you need 1% regulation, the current through the resistors for your divider should be 100 times greater than the current through the load.

Each LOAD would be 3.6 Ohm in the worst case (10Wx2 transferred to the load). The resistors on the divider should be 100 times smaller, namely, 0.036 Ohm each. So your VERY hypothetical divider would be consuming 2kW!!!. Your battery would be discharged in no time, the resistors of your divider would be bulky things heating the environment like a home radiator... so it should be obvious that the voltage divider solution is not applicable for any application that requires a significant amount of power to be transferred. As a rule of thumb, if the resistors of your divider are smaller than 1K each you should probably consider another solution.

Comment: Ahh...yeah, I figured 3.6 Ohms would be too small, even for a book problem. Hmm...then how would I go about making sure my divider only supplies 10 W then?

Answer (score 1):

Some op-amps like the TCA0372 can output a high enough current to use them as a power source, hook it up like this and it will source or sink current to maintain its output at the voltage that is on its non-inverting input (the middle of the voltage divider).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyq7n2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just make sure that whatever op-amp you choose can output about 1A.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuJhNl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are some ambiguities in the question. One way to interpret and approach the question is to consider one side only and convert the source plus divider to its Thevenin equivalent.

Now with the required 1% difference of +V for Rload being 0W or 10W. You can solve for R.

After you get R, you should do at least one other calculation. Calculate the power dissipation of R even when there is no load. The question is perhaps trying to show how ridiculously inefficient it is to use a voltage divider as a regulated power source.

Your calculation for Rload of 10W being 3.6 ohms is correct if you ignore that there may be an 1% output drop. Since there would not be an 1% output drop if the +V and -V loads are balanced, so the 3.6 ohms should be fine here.

Comment: How can you answer a question ignoring the 1% regulation requirement?